# modernWPFUI + powershell = System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder

Tags: wpf, powershell

I want to use the ModernWPFUI Theme on Powershell.
Generally, i use only XAML in powershell for a better GUI, so i really don't know too much
Now, this is my test code:

XAML(test.xaml):

```
   <Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"   
    
x:Name="Window"
Title="Test" Height="68.293" Width="462.195">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ModernWpf;component/ControlsResources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ModernWpf;component/ThemeResources/Light.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

PS1(run.ps1):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')      | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('.\assembly\ModernWpf.dll')              | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('.\assembly\ModernWpf.Controls.dll')     | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('.\assembly\System.ValueTuple.dll')      | out-null

function LoadXml ($global:filename)
{
    $XamlLoader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument)
    $XamlLoader.Load($filename)
    return $XamlLoader
}

$XamlMainWindow=LoadXml("test.xaml")
$Reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XamlMainWindow)
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)
$Global:Current_Folder =(get-location).path 


$Form.ShowDialog()
```

result:

```
MethodInvocationException: (path)\run.ps1: 15: 1
Line |
  15 | $ Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader] :: Load ($ Reader)
     | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Load" with arguments "1": "An exception was thrown when specifying a value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder'."

Invalid operation: (path)\run.ps1: 22: 1
Line |
  22 | $ Form.ShowDialog ()
     | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | A method cannot be called on a null-valued expression.
```

I tried to edit in  or add it "clr-namespace:ModernWpf;assembly=ModernWpf" with the same result.